# Getting mouse click position in pictureBox C#

Tags: c#, picturebox

I'm trying to get the mouse click coordinates on a picture box and putting the information in a textbox.

I'm able to get the mouse click coordinates in the form but I'm unable to get the mouse coordinates in the picturebox (nothing happens when I click in picturebox).  I've looked at the answers from similar question on stackoverflow but nothing seems to be working for me.

Here is my complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testGraphiqueCSharp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseClick(e);
            textBox1.Text = e.X.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = e.Y.ToString();
        }

       private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = e.X.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = e.Y.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("mouse up");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is working in my computer.

Answer (score 4):

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var mouseEventArgs = e as MouseEventArgs;
    if (mouseEventArgs != null) textBox1.Text = "X= " + mouseEventArgs.X + " Y= " + mouseEventArgs.Y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Initially i was not able to cast the mouse event...the above solved the issue!!

Answer (score 3):

**Your code is perfect and working in my computer** 
`Please make sure that that event is actually called by putting debug point.`

here are an images for the same
**UI part** 
[image]

**Code part**
[image]

**Output** (while i am clicking on image) 
[image]

Comment: I've put a Console.WriteLine("mouse up"); message in the pictureBox1_MouseUp, and this never shows in the output window!  Seems like this event is never called!  Why is that?!?

Answer (score 1):

You have called that function when mouseup event occurs. you should call the function when the picturebox is clicked.try events like tapped to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the pictureBox1_MouseUp by this

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MouseEventArgs eM = (MouseEventArgs)e;
    textBox1.Text = eM.X.ToString();
    textBox2.Text = eM.Y.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("mouse up");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  I stuck this code in constructor of form.

```
pictureBox1.MouseClick += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Mouse Clicked at X: {0} Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y));
```